# How to structure sqlite tables for ios quiz app

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I am designing a "quiz" app which has the following format:

One main question at the top, then 5 sub-questions related to that top question which they have to answer on a scale of 1-5 as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I want to use an sqlite database but I am unsure how to structure it/ how many tables and what the columns should be.

Would this work:

`questionTbl: questionID, questionText (for the main question at the top)
subquestionATbl: questionID, subQuestionAID, subQuestionA, subQuestionACorrectAnswer
subquestionBTbl: questionID, subQuestionBID, subQuestionB, subQuestionBCorrectAnswer
subquestionCTbl: etc 
subquestionDTbl: etc
subquestionETbl: etc`

Or can I keep it less complicated with fewer tables?

`questionTbl: questionID, questionText`(for the main question at the top)`, subQuestionA, subQuestionB, subQuestionC, subQuestionD, subQuestionE
answersTbl: questionID, subQuestionACorrectAnswer, subQuestionBCorrectAnswer, subQuestionCCorrectAnswer, subQuestionDCorrectAnswer,subQuestionECorrectAnswer`

What are your suggestions?

Comment: Are you more comfortable with SQL directly than with Core Data (tables instead of objects)?

Comment: I am just starting to learn how to deal with SQL and I've been told it's easier than learning Core Data. Is that the case?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you're currently used to. If you know OO well then Core Data should probably be easier than pure SQL. Might be an idea to have a 10 minute browse over the results of https://www.google.com/search?q=use+sql+or+core+data

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer the question, let's consider an example:

> Question: "Once upon a time there was a sow with three little pigs... [continue with the story of the three little pigs here]"
>
> Subquestion A: "What was the first little piggy's house made of?"
>
> Answer 1: "Straw"
> Answer 2: "Sticks"
> Answer 3: "Bricks"
> Answer 4: "Steel"

Assuming that example is illustrative of how your questions would be presented, I might therefore lean towards an entity relation model like so:

1. A `question` table for a list of the top level questions (e.g. the story of the three little pigs);
2. A `subquestion` table for a list of the "Selection A", "Selection B", ..., questions (e.g. "What was the first little piggy's house made of?");
3. If you wanted, you might even have a third entity for the text associated with the five choices, 1 through 5 (e.g. "Straw"):

[image: ER diagram]

I definitely don't think you want separate tables for "Selection A", "Selection B", etc.

And, remember, if you're going to use SQLite, consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which makes it *much* easier.